# SO review potential anomalies

Tags: support, stack-overflow, review

Went to do some reviewing on SO and one of the "first answers" that came up to review had no username showing and incorrect number of votes (0 instead of 11).

It was also not the user's first answer (81k rep), and was posted over a fortnight ago.

Review presented to me:

> [image]

The answer as viewed in the question:

> [image]

Not moaning, just reportin' in case something is out of align that needs fixin'!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an audit question.  It's there to make sure you're paying attention (you are, great).  When you select an action other than skip it will either pat you on the back for paying attention, or slap you on the wrist for doing the "wrong thing".  Fail enough audits and you can be banned from reviewing for a period of time.

The username isn't shown and the votes are altered so that it's not as visible from the review queue that the question is an audit.

Comment: Ah fair enough, thanks. I had one of these the other day, and passed. This time I skipped as not sure what to do. I presume "no action needed" have been appropriate?

Comment: @James Some audits are of good content in which you should no action, and some are of bad content in which you should clearly have some action to perform.  Just do whatever you think should be done based on the question's content and you should be fine.